# How can I filter my model instances based off of their categorical attribute, using a select option input field (selecting from a drop down menu)

Tags: django-models, django-queryset, django-filters

I have a blog Post model, and one of its attributes is a categorical attribute (store_type). This categorical attribute contains 4 possible values: cafe, coffee house, dessert cafe, and restaurant

I want to create a filter so that I can display the posts according to the type of store associated with that post, and I want the user to be able to use a drop down menu, rather than search by character field input. Here's my model.

I have already made a filter for the title, and it works accordingly.

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    store_choices = [
            ('1', 'cafe'),
            ('2', 'dessert cafe'),
            ('3', 'coffee house'),
            ('4', 'restaurant')
        ]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    review = models.TextField(default='Paragraph 1', max_length=3000)
    store_type = models.CharField(choices=store_choices, max_length=100)
```

In my views.py file, I created a filter class, and I passed the store_type list into context so that I could reference these values in my template.

```py
def PostFilter(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()

    store_type = [
        ('cafe'),
        ('dessert cafe'),
        ('coffee house'),
        ('restaurant')
    ]

    title_query = request.GET.get('title')
    store_type_query = request.GET.get('store_type')

    if valid_query(title_query):
        qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=title_query)

    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'store_type': store_type
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/search.html', context)
```

Then in my html template, I try to reference these categorical values:

```py
<div class="container py-5">
  <form method="GET" action=".">
    <!-- Search by title -->
    <div class="form-row d-block">
      <div class="form-group col">
        <label for="title">Store Name</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="title" placeholder="Name contains..." />
              <span class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </div>
              </span> 
          </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Search by store type-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-6">
        <div class="container mt-4 mb-4">
        <label for="storetype">Store Type</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="store_type">
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
            {% for store in store_type %}
              <option value="{{ store }}"> {{ store }} </option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>
```

Again, my filtering method seems to work fine when it comes to filtering by character field input, but I can't seem to get a working filter that uses a drop down menu (option select) method.